# Linux Inactive memory

Tags: linux, solr

When I fire command `vmstat -s` on my linux box , I got stats as :

```
vmstat -s
16305800  total memory
16217112  used memory
9117400  active memory
6689116  inactive memory
88688  free memory
151280  buffer memory
```

I have skipped some details that is shown with this command.

I understand these terms :

- Active memory is memory that is being used by a particular process.
- Inactive memory is memory that was allocated to a process that is no
  longer running.

Just want to know, is there any way I can get the processes, with which Inactive memory is allocated ? 
Because top or vmstat command still shows the used memory as sum of Active and Inactive memory and I can see only processes that are using active memory but what processes are using inactive memory is still a question for me.

I would like to add one thing, Apache solr is also running on the same machine, can it be the possibility, that solr indexes are using the inactive memory ? (Just a thought since I am very new to solr)

Comment: How would it refer to the processes if they no longer exist?

Comment: That's what I am not sure of, I mean I can see the active processes are using memory(9 GB) that is fine, but where near about 6 GB memory is being used, that a question for me.

Comment: That's not what inactive is. According to http://books.gigatux.nl/mirror/linuxperformanceguide/0131486829/ch03lev1sec2.html, inactive is memory that hasn't been used recently, so it can be paged out to disk. But it's still assigned to processes.

Comment: Anyway, this question would be better for unix.stackexchange.com, as it's not a programming question.